# Ruby - undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, associations, string

More than 3 hours I am trying to solve pretty easy error (on the first glance):

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

but still no success.

I have the DB table `products`, which contains the columns `category_id` and `manufacturer_id`.

Associations:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  belongs_to :category
  ...
end
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base # the same for Manufacturer
  has_ancestry
  has_many :products

end
```

Trying to grab some data:

```
Product.where('category_id IS NOT NULL AND manufacturer_id IS NOT NULL').each do |product|
  ...
  puts product.manufacturer.name # here's the error
  puts product.category.name # here's the error
  ...
end
```

I fetched all rows, where is not NIL value in the columns `manufacturer_id` and `category_id`... so how can I get this error?

Also, I've tried:

```
 ...
  puts product.manufacturer.name unless product.manufacturer_id.nil?
  puts product.category.name unless product.category_id.nil?
  ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't mention the line where the error is on.

Comment: this one `puts product.manufacturer.name` or this one: `puts product.category.name`, I mentioned only the problematic ones.

Comment: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass you mentioned in the question. Where is that **empty?** related line.

Comment: It's the line where I try to print out the name of manufacturer or category... here: `puts product.manufacturer.name` or here: `puts product.category.name`

Comment: I added the comments in the OP

Comment: You need to post more of the error message. The error is obviously not directly in the code you posted since there is no `empty?` method anywhere to be seen. Post the full error message or at least the most relevant parts of the call stack.

Comment: Do you have a before_filter set that is calling the empty? method?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely deleted a manufacturer or category so there's no corresponding record to match the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Problably is a business logic problem on your database considering your query.

IMHO u are calling some objects that will not be valid ones. Check your database to see if all registers attend your validations logic.